# A problem with \times

Tags: symbols

I am at my wits end trying to get the following right in my document

> 10% x 90(degrees)

the syntax I have tried are the following

```
10\% $\times$ 90\degree (get the undefined symbol error)

$ 10\% \times 90\degree $ (get the undefined symbol error)

10\% \times 90\degree (get the missing $ symbol error)
```

Can someone please tell me how to get this simple thing right?

Comment: should you re-title the question with 'problem with \degree'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An examination of the actual error message reveals that it's not `\times` but `\degree` that's causing the "undefined control sequence" problem. You need to define the macro `\degree` first. I suggest you define it as follows:

```
\newcommand\degree{{}^\circ}
```

With this definition, the macro must be used in math mode -- which, I assume, is OK.

You can then write

```
$10\% \times 90\degree$
```

Answer (score 16):

I suggest you to use the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package for this and `90°` has to be written as

```
\SI{90}{\degree}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$ 10\% \times \SI{90}{\degree} $

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Note that `\SI{90}{\degree}` can also be written as `\ang{90}` and that `10\%` is better to be written as `\SI{10}{\percent}`, as noted by LaRiFaRi, so the MWE can be changed to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$ \SI{10}{\percent} \times \ang{90} $

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]